# How to put ads below the content of these pages

Tags: wordpress

How to put ads below the content of these pages.... tried many plugins like ad injection and advanced ads but none work... these posts were created by using arena products store plugin.... but not able to put ads below these posts... http://techgrabo.com/product/iball-andi-5k-infinito-2/ ...................... http://techgrabo.com/comparison/innjoo-fire-plus-vs-wiko-slide-2/

this is the  code

```
    <?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: APS Arena Products 
 * Plugin URI: http://www.webstudio55.com/plugins/arena/
 * Description: Add Products attributes website in less than 5 minutes, without knowledge of php and WordPress coding.
 * Version: 1.2
 * Text Domain: aps-text
 * Author: Shahzad Anjum
 * Author URI: http://www.webstudio55.com/
*/

    // define common constants
    define( 'APS_VER', 1.2 );
    define( 'APS_NAME', 'APS Arena Products' );
    define( 'APS_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL .'/' .str_replace(basename( __FILE__), '', plugin_basename(__FILE__)) );
    define( 'APS_DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR .'/' .str_replace(basename( __FILE__), '', plugin_basename(__FILE__)) );

    // register activation hook
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'aps_plugin_activate' );

    // register deactivation hook
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'aps_plugin_deactivate' );

    // get ready for localization
    add_action('plugins_loaded', 'aps_localization_init');

    function aps_localization_init() {
        load_plugin_textdomain( 'aps-text', false, APS_DIR .'/langs/' ); 
    }

    // include APS post type
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-post.php');

    // include APS attributes
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-attributes.php');

    // include APS functions
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-functions.php');

    // include APS settings
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-settings.php');

    // include APS image resizing
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-image.php');

    // include APS widgets
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-widgets.php');

    // include APS Control Panel
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-control.php');

    // include APS Shortcodes
    include(APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-shortcodes.php');

    // add menu page
    add_action('admin_menu', 'register_aps_menu_pages');

    function register_aps_menu_pages() {
        $groups_page = add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=aps-products', 'APS Groups', 'APS Groups', 'manage_options', 'aps-groups', 'build_aps_groups_page');
        $attributes_page = add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=aps-products', 'APS Attributes', 'APS Attributes', 'manage_options', 'aps-attributes', 'build_aps_attributes_page');
        $filters_page = add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=aps-products', 'APS Filters', 'APS Filters', 'manage_options', 'aps-filters', 'build_aps_filters_page');
        $settings_page = add_submenu_page('edit.php?post_type=aps-products', 'APS Settings', 'APS Settings', 'manage_options', 'aps-settings', 'build_aps_settings_page');
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' .$groups_page, 'aps_add_scripts_to_groups' );
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' .$attributes_page, 'aps_add_scripts_to_groups' );
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' .$filters_page, 'aps_add_scripts_to_groups' );
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' .$settings_page, 'aps_add_scripts_to_settings' );
    }

    function aps_add_scripts_to_groups() {
        // enqueue jquery ui sortable
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );

        // enqueue admin css styles
        wp_enqueue_style( 'aps-admin-style', APS_URL .'css/aps-admin.css' );
    }

    function aps_add_scripts_to_settings() {
        // enqueue jquery ui sortable
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );

        // enqueue admin css styles
        wp_enqueue_style( 'aps-admin-style', APS_URL .'css/aps-admin.css' );

        // enqueue new wp color picker css
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );

        // enqueue new wp color picker script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_media();
    }

    // add an option on activation
    function aps_plugin_activate() {
        $installed = get_option('aps_installed');

        if (!$installed) {
            // save default plugin settings
            aps_load_default_settings();

            // assign sidebar widgets
            aps_sidebar_widgets_setup();

            // update option insatlled = true
            update_option('aps_installed', true);
        }
    }

    function aps_add_settings_link( $links ) {
        $settings_link = '<a href="edit.php?post_type=aps-products&page=aps-settings">' .__( 'Settings' ) . '</a>';
        array_push( $links, $settings_link );
        return $links;
    }
    $plugin = plugin_basename(__FILE__);
    add_filter( "plugin_action_links_$plugin", 'aps_add_settings_link' );

    // add featured image support
    function aps_add_thumbnail_support() {
        if (!get_theme_support('post-thumbnails')) {
            add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
        }
    }
    add_action('after_setup_theme', 'aps_add_thumbnail_support', 11);

    // load single aps-products template
    function load_aps_single_template($template) {
        global $post;

        if ($post->post_type == 'aps-products') {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-single.php';
        } elseif ($post->post_type == 'aps-comparisons') {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-compare.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
    add_filter('single_template', 'load_aps_single_template');

    // load aps-brands archive template
    function aps_brands_template($template) {
        if (is_tax('aps-brands')) {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-archive.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
    add_filter('archive_template', 'aps_brands_template');

    // set posts per page on brands archive
    function aps_archive_posts_per_page( $default ) {

        if (is_tax('aps-brands') || is_search()) {
            $settings = get_aps_settings();
            return ($num = $settings['num-products']) ? $num : 12;
        }
        return $default;
    }
    add_filter( 'option_posts_per_page', 'aps_archive_posts_per_page' );

    // load reviews template for aps-products
    function aps_reviews_template( $template ) {
        global $post;

        if (is_single() && $post->post_type == 'aps-products') {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-reviews.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'comments_template', 'aps_reviews_template' );

    // load index page template for home page
    function aps_index_page_template( $template ) {
        global $post;

        $settings = get_aps_settings();
        $page = (int) $settings['index-page'];

        if (is_page($page)) {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-index.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'page_template', 'aps_index_page_template' );

    // load compare page template for Compare page
    function aps_compare_page_template( $template ) {
        global $post;
        $settings = get_aps_settings();

        if (is_page($settings['comp-page'])) {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-compare.php';
        } else if (is_page($settings['comp-list'])) {
            $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-comparisons.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'page_template', 'aps_compare_page_template' );

    // search templates for aps-products
    function aps_products_search_template($template) {
        global $wp_query;
        if ($wp_query->is_search) {
            $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');

            if ($post_type == 'aps-products' ) {
                $template = APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-search.php';
            }
        }       
        return $template;   
    }
    add_filter('search_template', 'aps_products_search_template');
```

Comment: what kind of ads are you talking about? adsense ads or post ads? Be specific

Comment: i am trying to put adsense ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the developer of [Advanced Ads](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ads/) and had users with similar issues before.

Using a function to place the ad in the correct template would definitely be a solution. If you use a (manual) Placement then you would only need to do this once and then can manage the ad delivered there through the dashboard.

Depending on how the plugin generates the content, you could also try to set the priority of the injection to 0, 1, 5, 10, 20 and see if one of these works.

Comment: the code you posted above reads like there is a template file in `APS_DIR .'/inc/aps-single.php';` Try to make modifications there to see if it works.

Comment: perfect, I was finally able to be quick enough to help here :). Would you mind choosing my answer as the correct one? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your theme or plugin, whether it gives you that kind of functionality or not. But its pretty simple if you have access to your theme files. Just goto **wp-content/themes/theme-name/page.php**, usually this file is responsible for all your page related design. So just add your adsense code before the get_footer function.

Comment: Ok try it in single.php, i think you are using the blog layout instead of page layout. Also add all the code of single.php in your question.

Comment: tried your method it was showing ads on main blog posts instead of those plugin posts.....

Comment: Well i think you are using some kind of plugin that might have its own files to display posts. If that is the case then you will have to find that file inside the aps plugin folder. It might be named something single-aps-products

Comment: it has aps products.php file and code is in the question

Comment: no this is not the file. It should have the wordpress while loop in it.

Comment: can you pls look into all files of plugin... search on google you can easily find all files of the plugins